# How can I find the greatest of this expression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the greatest of the expression
$$P=a \sqrt{12-b}+\sqrt{b\left(12+a^2\right)}+66\sqrt{a^2+b+3}-\left(a^2+b\right)^2$$
 with $a >0$, $0<b\leq 12$. I tried

```
NMaximize[{a Sqrt[12 - b] + Sqrt[b (12 + a^2)] + 
66 Sqrt[a^2 + b + 3] - (a^2 + b)^2, {a > 0, b > 0, b <= 12}}, {a, b}]
```

I got

> {174., {a -> 1.92567, b -> 2.2918}}

When I tried

```
Maximize[{a Sqrt[12 - b] + Sqrt[b (12 + a^2)] + 66 Sqrt[a^2 + b + 3] - (a^2 + b)^2, {a > 0, b > 0, b <= 12}}, {a, b}]
```

My computer runs too long. Can I use the command `Maximize`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a symbolic derivation by applying `Reduce` to the gradient:

```
expr = a Sqrt[12 - b] + Sqrt[b (12 + a^2)] + 66 Sqrt[a^2 + b + 3] - (a^2 + b)^2;
Reduce[{And @@ Thread[D[expr, {{a, b}, 1}] == {0, 0}], a > 0, b > 0}, {a, b}]
```

giving

$$a=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{15 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}-\sqrt{3
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\land b=-3 \left(\sqrt{5}-3\right)$$

which numerically agrees with your result from `NMinimize`.

I had trouble getting `Maximize` to give a result in a reasonable computation time.

By the way, the inverse of the norm of the gradient of your function looks sort of like Darth Vader's lightsaber. Here's some code for a plotting method:

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {(1.0 Arg[-z] + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]), 
    Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], Min[Abs[z], 1]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
ComplexPlotR2[f_, {x0_, x1_, dx_}, {y0_, y1_, dy_}, mag_] := 
  Image[hue[
     mag f[#[[All, All, 1]], #[[All, All, 2]]] &@
      Outer[List, Range[x0, x1, dx], Range[y1, y0, -dy]]]\[Transpose],
    ColorSpace -> Hue, Magnification -> 1];
CCompileR2[expr_] := 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, Evaluate[expr], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

And here's the plot of the inverse norm gradient:

```
expr = x Sqrt[12 - y] + Sqrt[(12 + x^2) y] - (x^2 + y)^2 + 
   66 Sqrt[3 + x^2 + y];
ComplexPlotR2[
 CCompileR2[1/Norm[Grad[expr, {x, y}]]], {0.01, 4, 0.007}, {0.01, 6, 
  0.007}, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: `{a, b}` is a two-dimensional variable, while `Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}]` is a one-dimensional region. Domains and regions behave differently in this regard.

Comment: @kirma: Thanks, but I tried using `{a \[Element] Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}], 
 b \[Element] Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}]}` and also got the same error. Is that not the right way to specify it?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus If you absolutely want to use the region form, this works, for instance: `{a, b} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[a >= 0 && b >= 0, {a, b}]`. It doesn't make much sense in this case, though. You can use simple constraints for `a` and `b` as their use is defined on the documentation. See the form `Maximize[{f, cons}, {x, y, ...}]`.